# Make 1 promotion code redeemable once per customer

Tags: stripe-payments

We sell online products (e.g. PDF books, Zoom meetings) via our website and we use Stripe as the payment processor. All the purchases are by checkout sessions (and by redirecting our users to Stripe checkout page). We allow our users to enter promotion codes on the Stripe checkout page that **we cannot control** after redirecting the user to.

When we want to promote a product we'd like to generate **1 promotion code** and spread the code to our users that has the potential to buy the promoted product. At the same time we'd like to restrict our users to be able to use that promotion code **only once**.

We are aware of that 1 promotion code can be tied to 1 customer but we don't want to bulk create promotion codes upfront, *and* set `max_redemptions` for each one of them. Nevertheless 1 promotion code may have its `max_redemptions` and/or `expires_at` set (or its parent coupon might have been set so).

Example;

- We announced a new product `P`.
- We then create a new coupon `C` and a new promotion code `R`.
- We designated that there are 3 users might be interested in product `P`, users as follows; `U1`, `U2` and `U3`.

Now my question is, regardless of the coupon's / promotion code's lifetimes (`redeems_by` and `expires_at` respectively) and redemption settings (`max_redemptions`);
can we make it so that after user `U1` purchased product `P` with promotion code `R`, users `U2` and `U3` both still have a chance to use promotion code `R` to purchase product `P` discounted **where user `U1` cannot use the promotion code `R` again?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really don't get it why one give -1 without any explanation. Like what, didn't you like my issue?

Comment: FYI this is a Community-moderated site, and site members are encouraged to participate in things like voting, based on the site's guidelines. Nobody is required to give an explanation. If you take the [tour] and read [ask], as well as creating a [mcve], you might get a better sense of what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In this case, there's no programming question: it's a general set of requirements, looking for ideas from the Community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible with a single Promotion Code today. In order to meet the requirements you outlined:

1. Create the Coupon applying the discount as required.
2. Create `n` (1 per customer) Promotion Codes for the previously created Coupon.
3. For each code, apply a [customer limit](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts#limit-by-customer) via the `customer` parameter.
4. You'll also need to limit each code to a single redemption (`max_redemptions: 1`) in order to prevent the same customer from re-using the code.

Alternatively you could apply the discount upfront during session creation via the [`discounts[coupon]` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts-coupon). You'd need to track redemptions against your users separately however.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Under the circumstances that seems the most viable option even though we don't want it (to create `n` promotion codes upfront). AFAIK it'd be the same on the surface for our users; same string for the promotion code but different IDs.

Comment: BTW I'll wait for a while, for any other response, and then select yours as the accepted answer.